# Migration with Default Value current time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im trying to write a migration in which I have a field to datetime..

Right now my migration for field is like this..

```
t.datetime :date, default: Time.now
```

I know that this will create a default time at which migration ran.. and it will be set to all fields..

But what i want is to have a default time at which that row field will be getting created.Like the same as created_at

Comment: But why u need custom field even though u have "created_at" field...? its worthless

Comment: @Jeet cause im not allowed to change the db structure

Answer (score 1):

You can use an **Active Record Callback** for that, like the **before_create**

Example:

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :record_signup

  private

  def record_signup
    self.signed_up_on = Date.today
  end
end
```

And you migration won't need a default value.

```
t.datetime :date
```

Source and Example: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html